# Access inner enum value outside namespace

Tags: c++, enums, nested

Given the following minimal example:

**foo.hpp:**

```
class foo {       
    public:       
        enum bar {
            ONE,  
            TWO,  
            THREE 
        };        
        bar b;    
        foo ();   
};
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.hpp"       

foo::foo () : b(ONE) { }
```

How can I do what I'm trying to do below?

```
#include "foo.hpp"        

int main () {             
    foo *f = new foo();   
/* None of these work:    
    f->b = TWO;           
    f->b = foo::bar::TWO; 
    f->b = bar::TWO;      
*/                        
    return 0;             
}
```

I'm leaning toward the conclusion that this is not idiomatic in C++ and I must wrap the enum with the class in an outer namespace, or otherwise reorganize.  What are the options and/or best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f->b = foo::TWO;
```

should work

Comment: To clarify: enum values are members of their enclosing namespace (which in this case, is the `foo` class), unless the enum is declared like `enum class bar` (in which case, they'd be named like `foo::bar::TWO`).

Comment: Why I thought `bar::TWO` worth trying but not `foo::TWO` I dunno.  Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember foo::bar::TWO would actually work under Visual Studio (at least 2005), while on GCC it does not - which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ prior to C++11 enums (the enum name itself AND the values) are in the scope of the enclosing namespace/class.

So you would access it as: `f->b = foo::TWO;` (as seen in the other answer).

However you can utilize nested structs to make enum management a bit easier:

```
class foo {       
    public:       
        struct bar {
            enum Type {
            ONE,  
            TWO,  
            THREE  }
        };        
        bar::Type b;    
        foo ();   
};
```

Now you can qualify the name with your struct helper.

```
#include "foo.hpp"        

int main () {             
    foo *f = new foo();   
    f->b = foo::bar::TWO; 

    return 0;             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators are members of class. So you can write either as

```
f->b = foo::TWO;
```

or

```
f->b = f->TWO;
```

or even as

```
f->b = foo::bar::TWO;
```

provided that your compiler supports the C++ 2011 Standard